# How to easily overwrite/change multiple php variables

Tags: php, loops, variables, encode

I'm building a pdf with php and noticed that my strings didn't work, because they were in the UTF-8 Format. `utf8_decode($str)` works fine but I have plenty of variables that I would have to decode this way. My code looks something like this:

```
function makePDF(titleStr, bodyStr, headerStr, and more...)
{

   //TO-DO

   $pdf->Cell(20, 6, $titleStr, 1, 1, 'L', false);
   $pdf->Cell(15, 6, $bodyStr, 1, 1, 'L', true);
   $pdf->Cell(50, 6, $headerStr, 1, 1, 'R', false);
}
```

I want to find a way to decode them all at once in a loop or something without having to do this for each variable or changing any other code that I already have:

```
$titleStr = utf8_decode($titleStr);
$bodyStr  = utf8_decode($bodyStr);
...and so on
```

Anyone an idea how to do this more easily?

Comment: do you have those string variables in an array? Then you could do this within a loop.

Comment: How about extending the class of whatever $pdf is and overriding the Cell() method. You can then just decode the string before calling the parent method?

Comment: thanks, I didn't think of that! That would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all of your function's arguments with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to retrieve them, [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply the UTF8 decoding, and [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) read them back into simple string variables.

```
<?php

function makePDF($titleStr, $bodyStr, $headerStr)
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    $args = array_map(function($args){
        return utf8_decode($args);
    }, $args);

    list($titleStr, $bodyStr, $headerStr) = $args;

    var_dump($titleStr);
    var_dump($bodyStr);
    var_dump($headerStr);
}

makePDF('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Outputs:

> ```
> string(3) "foo" 
> string(3) "bar" 
> string(3) "baz"
> ```

You will need to copy/paste your method signature into the `list()` call, but that's fairly simple.

---

For fun, if you want to skip the copy/paste step, you can switch in `func_get_args()` for [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) and use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to reassign the arguments:

```
<?php

function makePDF($titleStr, $bodyStr, $headerStr)
{
    $args = get_defined_vars();

    $args = array_map(function($args){
        return utf8_decode($args) . rand(0,10);
    }, $args);

    foreach($args as $key => $arg){
        // The two $$ show that this is a variable variable.
        $$key = $arg;
    }

    var_dump($titleStr);
    var_dump($bodyStr);
    var_dump($headerStr);
}

makePDF('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

> ```
> string(4) "foo5"
> string(4) "bar5"
> string(4) "baz9"
> ```

*I've added `rand()` in the `array_map()` callable to demonstrate that the assignment is actually taking place here.

Comment: thanks, I really liked your answer because not only did it solve my problem but I also learned a lot :)